# Prevent PDF file emebeded in iframe from being automatically downloaded (in phone browsers)

Tags: android, html, pdf, iframe, browser

I am embedding pdf files in iframe tag like this:

```
 <iframe src="<?php echo $pdf_file['guid']; ?>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This is working fine in desktop. But when the same page is viewed in phone (Android - Chrome, Firefox) the PDF file is not being displayed but is being downloaded automatically instead.

I want to prevent the download and allow it to be presented in ifrmae tag in phones also. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

you can something like this with webview or using library for load pdf file :

```
String myPdfUrl = "http://example.com/awesome.pdf";
String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + myPdfUrl;
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: This is done in wordpress site (using php). How can I achieve it in php without using android's functions. AFAIK the code you gave is for android application. Right ? Thanks .